# CKEditor 4 does not display button image

Tags: button, ckeditor, icons

I did the plugin according to the instructions.
https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/plugin_sdk_sample.html
I installed a plug-in that they developed the Timestamp, but the picture even does not display their plug-in.
http://prntscr.com/j9wzxq
http://prntscr.com/j9x078

(CKEditor 4.8.0 (revision 230f715))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icon name has to match button name in lowercase. Please read the [guide](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/plugin_sdk_sample.html#plugin-source-code) carefully one more time.

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'pluginname', {
    icons: 'buttonname',
...

editor.ui.addButton( 'Buttonname',...
```

In your case this will be:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'imgcollection', {
    icons: 'piccollection',
...

editor.ui.addButton( 'Piccollection',...
```